# Is 'interpretating' a word?

Tags: is-it-a-word

Is 'Interpretating' a misrepresentation?
I wrote interpretating in my exam. 
I found some examples that using interpretating.
Can I use interpretating?

Comment: What do _you_ think interpretating means?

Answer (score 2):

It is a word (as it can be found in some dictionaries), but it's archaic and shouldn't be used. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/news-trend-watch/is-interpretate-a-word-20170321) says the following:

> *Interpretate* is a real word, but it is now regarded as an archaic form, and the preferred verb with this meaning is *interpret*. As with similar controversial words like *conversate* and *orientate*, it is criticized as being needlessly long. Since good rhetorical style favors few wasted words, it follows (for many people) that good vocabulary choices should not waste letters.

Comment: I'd disagree that "orientate" is archaic, personally - it's what you do to a new worker during an orientation, e.g. "What are you doing today?" "I'm orientating the new hires."

Comment: @nick012000 *Orientate* doesn't seem to be archaic. It's listed because it is controversial.